# Compare multiple columns, but only those having valid values, and create y/n flag if all are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a Y/N flag, where Y indicates every valid value in every column in a given row is equal, and N otherwise. I need to exclude from consideration any column that contains nulls, blanks, or all zeroes. Suppose:

```
CREATE TABLE z_test
(ID INT NOT NULL,
D1 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
D2 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
D3 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
D4 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
DFLAG CHAR(1)NULL)

INSERT INTO z_test VALUES (1,NULL,' ','000000','00000000',NULL)
INSERT INTO z_test VALUES (1,'20120101','0000','20120101','00000000',NULL)
INSERT INTO z_test VALUES (2,'20100101','20100101','20100101','20100101',NULL)
INSERT INTO z_test VALUES (2,'00000000','20090101','0','20090101',NULL)
INSERT INTO z_test VALUES (3,'00000000','20090101',NULL,'20120101',NULL)
INSERT INTO z_test VALUES (3,'20100101',' ',NULL,'20100101',NULL)
```

The desired output (excluding D1 through D4, though I don't want to drop them) is:

```
ID       DFLAG
---------------
1        N
1        Y
2        Y
2        Y
3        N
3        Y
```

Speed is not a concern as this query will not be run very often but it is on a largish table.

Any pointers or suggestions would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Why is the last result `Y`, when the row has both a blank and a `NULL`?

Comment: but the other two legitimate values are equal. '20100101' = '20100101'

Comment: samy yi is correct that the last one should be a Y because 20100101 is legitimate. Running version 2008 of SQL Server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, 
       CASE 
         WHEN C = 1 THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'N' 
       END AS DFLAG 
FROM   z_test 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D) C 
                    FROM   (VALUES(D1), 
                                  (D2), 
                                  (D3), 
                                  (D4)) V(D) 
                    WHERE  LEN(D) > 0 /*Excludes blanks and NULLs*/
                         AND D LIKE '%[^0]%'/*Excludes ones with only zero*/) CA
```

Comment: Does this not work in SQL-Server 2005? I get an _incorrect syntax near VALUES_.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - No you would need `UNION ALL` for 2005. i.e. `SELECT D1 UNION ALL SELECT D2 ... ` instead of `VALUES(D1),(D2) ... `

Comment: This works in 2008 but I confess it's a bit of SQL Kung Fu that is well beyond me. Thanks!

Comment: @user1126915 A sub query can reference columns from the outer query. It uses the `VALUES` clause to unpivot the column values into rows then you can just use normal aggregate functions on them such as `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as well as applying a normal `WHERE` clause.

Comment: +1 This is much better than my sequence of equals - it scales a lot better when you need to add D5, D6, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
select case when
    (D1 is null OR D2 is null OR LEN(REPLACE(D1,'0',''))=0 OR LEN(REPLACE(D2,'0',''))=0 OR D1=D2)
AND (D1 is null OR D3 is null OR LEN(REPLACE(D1,'0',''))=0 OR LEN(REPLACE(D3,'0',''))=0 OR D1=D3)
AND (D1 is null OR D4 is null OR LEN(REPLACE(D1,'0',''))=0 OR LEN(REPLACE(D4,'0',''))=0 OR D1=D4)
AND (D2 is null OR D3 is null OR LEN(REPLACE(D2,'0',''))=0 OR LEN(REPLACE(D3,'0',''))=0 OR D2=D3)
AND (D2 is null OR D4 is null OR LEN(REPLACE(D2,'0',''))=0 OR LEN(REPLACE(D4,'0',''))=0 OR D2=D4)
AND (D3 is null OR D4 is null OR LEN(REPLACE(D3,'0',''))=0 OR LEN(REPLACE(D4,'0',''))=0 OR D3=D4)
AND (LEN(REPLACE(D1,'0','')) > 0
     OR LEN(REPLACE(D2,'0','')) > 0
     OR LEN(REPLACE(D3,'0','')) > 0
     OR LEN(REPLACE(D4,'0','')) > 0)
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
from z_test
```

Here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/969ba/19) to sqlfiddle.

Comment: `LEN` and `RTRIM` is pointless as `LEN` doesn't count trailing blanks anyway.

Comment: That does not compare every value. If you would for example change D4 of the 4th record from `20090101` to `20090102` it would still be `Y` instead of the correct `N`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Started a similar approach but dismissed partway since i thought that there must be [something better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10626930/284240). +1

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DECLARE @z_test table
(ID INT NOT NULL,
D1 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
D2 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
D3 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
D4 VARCHAR(8)NULL,
DFLAG CHAR(1)NULL)

INSERT INTO @z_test VALUES (1,NULL,' ','000000','00000000',NULL)
INSERT INTO @z_test VALUES (1,'20120101','0000','20120101','00000000',NULL)
INSERT INTO @z_test VALUES (2,'20100101','20100101','20100101','20100101',NULL)
INSERT INTO @z_test VALUES (2,'00000000','20090101','0','20090101',NULL)
INSERT INTO @z_test VALUES (3,'00000000','20090101',NULL,'20120101',NULL)
INSERT INTO @z_test VALUES (3,'20100101',' ',NULL,'20100101',NULL)

;WITH Fixed AS
(SELECT --converts columns with all zeros and any spaces to NULL
     ID
         ,NULLIF(NULLIF(D1,''),0) AS D1
         ,NULLIF(NULLIF(D2,''),0) AS D2
         ,NULLIF(NULLIF(D3,''),0) AS D3
         ,NULLIF(NULLIF(D4,''),0) AS D4
    FROM @z_test
)
SELECT --final result set
    ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(D1,D2,D3,D4) IS NULL THEN 'N' --all columns null
        WHEN (D1 IS NULL OR D1=COALESCE(D1,D2,D3,D4)) --all columns either null or the same
            AND (D2 IS NULL OR D2=COALESCE(D1,D2,D3,D4))
            AND (D3 IS NULL OR D3=COALESCE(D1,D2,D3,D4))
            AND (D4 IS NULL OR D4=COALESCE(D1,D2,D3,D4))
            THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END
    FROM Fixed
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID          
----------- ----
1           N
1           Y
2           Y
2           Y
3           N
3           Y

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for this.

```
create function fnRowValid(@d1 varchar, @d2 varchar...)
returns bit ------ 1 for true and 0 for false
begin

  declare table @validvalue (val varchar)

  if isdate(d1) = 0 and isdate(d1) = 0 and ...
    return 0

  if isdate(@d1)
    insert into @validvalue (val) values (@d1)
  if isdate(@d2)
    insert into @validvalue (val) values (@d2)
  if isdate(@d3)
    insert into @validvalue (val) values (@d3)
  ...


  if exists (select 1 from @validvalue)
    if (select count(distinct val) from @validvalue) = 1
      return 1

  return 0

end
```

Then you can use this in the update statement...

```
update z_test
set dflag = dbo.fnRowValid(d1,d2,d3..)
```

Please don't flame me for this... I didn't test this code obviously.  And this is the first solution that popped into my head... not a real elegant but should work.  I'm not positive you can use table variables in a function either.  Sorry about the ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
With RnkSource As
  (
    Select Id, D1, D2, D3, D4, DFlag
      , Row_Number() Over ( Order By Id ) As RowNum
    From z_test
  )
  , Source As
  (
    Select RowNum, Id, 'D1' As Col, D1 As Val
    From RnkSource
    Union All
    Select RowNum, Id, 'D2', D2
    From RnkSource
    Union All
    Select RowNum, Id, 'D3', D3
    From RnkSource
    Union All
    Select RowNum, Id, 'D4', D4
    From RnkSource
  )
Select Id
  , Case When Count(*) = 4 Then 'Y' Else 'N' End As DFLAG
From Source As S
Where Len(Val) > 0
Group By RowNum, Id
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/969ba/41)